# Can we have GET transactions in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can we define GET transactions to get a particular data from an asset in composer??

Eg: Considering a scenario I have an asset named Vehicle and I want to define a transaction through which I can retrieve information of the particular vehicle providing the id of the vehicle.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read an asset (or assets) you can access them through the Node.js composer-client API, or you can deploy the composer-rest-server to expose your assets over REST.

Alternatively you can write a Transaction Processor function that uses the composer-runtime API to read and update the assets.

Please refer to the documentation and the developer guide for more details:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/